# many to many to many mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database that is structured so that I can do ONE query and get all the data I need.

this is how I have it structured now:

```
Products       Subcategory    Category
-------------  -------------  -------------
| id | name |  | id | name |  | id | name |
```

It makes sense to me to create two relational tables that ties the product to the subcategory, and the subcategory to the category (making it hierarchical):

```
prod_sub_relation             sub_cat_relation
----------------------------  ---------------------------
| id | prod_id | subcat_id |  | id | subcat_id | cat_id |
```

So the product can be in MULTIPLE subcategories, and the subcategory tells us what category the product is in.

With this structure, if I wanted to find all the products with a `category_id`, I'd have to query the `sub_cat_relation` table, then take that array and make another query for the `prod_sub_relation` table (and that's just messy).

My goal is to find all products, or all categories, or all subcategories with ONE id (whether it's `product_id`, `category_id`, or `subcategory_id`)

Is this possible? or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: you should check 'JOIN' operation in sql. With join its possible to make those 3 tables joined like only one table containing all columns from the 3 tables. So you can do one query to get all data you need from 3 tables. May be [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) can help you start

Comment: Soo - I'm new at this - any examples with my current structure in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @har07 you could use a simple `JOIN` on this one.
I am not exactly sure the other details of the structure of your tables but
I will show you based on what you have provided so far:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, c.Name as CategoryName, s.Name as SubCategoryName
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN SubCategory S
ON P.subcat_id = S.subcat_id
INNER JOIN Category C
ON S.cat_id = C.cat_id
```

You could then use a `WHERE` clause to specify which product you want to display along with its category and subcategory

```
SELECT P.ID, P.Name, C.Name as CategoryName, S.Name as SubCategoryName
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN SubCategory S
ON P.subcat_id = S.subcat_id
INNER JOIN Category C
ON S.cat_id = C.cat_id
WHERE P.ID = valuehereforyourID
```

To get the `Products` and `SubCategory` for a given `category ID` you just change the `WHERE` clause, like:

```
WHERE C.cat_id = ValueForCategoryIDhere
```

To get the `Products` and `Category` for a given `Subcategory ID` you just change the `WHERE` clause, like:

```
WHERE S.subcat_id = ValueForSubCategoryIDhere
```

Comment: Awe.some. what about if I have the category ID? How can I join the tables to either get all the subcategories or all the products?

Comment: Glad to be of help @tonylefler. GOD bless and Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Put each products' categories in an array, serialize the array, and store that in the DB...